# Set Up SVN on Win2008

Tags: apache, svn, windows-server-2008-r2, ibmhttpserver

i'm working on Windows Server 2008 R2. I installed the IBM HTTP Server V7 in order to set up my svn repository. The IBM server works, bot if i change the conf file, adding the needed modules, by starting it i get the following message:

`httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 62 of C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/HTTPServer/conf
  /admin.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/HTTPServer/modules/mod_dav_s
  vn.so into server: Unrecognized Win32 error code 14001
  Note the errors or messages above, and press the <ESC> key to exit.  22...`

I also tried to use Apache 2.2, but when i set the conf file, adding the modules, it starts, but it remains offline; this using the 64bit. The 32bit doesn't start. Tried also version 2.4 -> same behavior.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about svn server setup, you should try Subversion Edge. It's free and build for simplicity and also it's a complete and ease to install solution:

http://www.collab.net/products/subversion

Regards.

Comment: Well, i hoped to install something that runs as service and not as user application. Otherwise i could install VisualSVN Server.

Comment: @Emaborsa you definitely should consider VisualSVN Server in this case!

Comment: It runs as a Windows service 0_0

Comment: @Emaborsa You can definitely install and configure Subversion Edge to run as a windows service. Not sure what's your point.